# WebView also Gone when Sreen Time-Out

Tags: android

I would like to find a solution to allow my WebView still alive when screen time-out.

I am program to play music using WebView, it's working very properly if the screen alive but when the screen time-out my music in WebView also GONE.

## Here is my code:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://mp3skull.com/usher.html");
}
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mWebView.destroy();
    super.onPause();
}
 }
```

I am very shy to tell you that i tried to find this solution over a week but still can't done :(.

Hope you give me solution on this matter.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove onPause() method in your class like below code:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://mp3skull.com/usher.html");
}
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Comment: Dear Disnesh. I can't remove onPause() because this method for stop music in WebView when user pressed Back Button. Do you have other way without remove onPause? Thank you Very much Disnesh.

Comment: ok,try this remove the statement mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE); for onPause() method..!

Comment: Dinesh, already removed mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE); but music in WebView still gone when screen time-out. Thanks you for helping me.

Comment: try this remove two statements mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE); mWebView.destroy(); in onPause() Method

Comment: Dear Dinesh, If removed two of these statement the music still play not stop when user pressed back-button, then user can't stop the music playing untill they go to clear memory.

Comment: Is there a way to keep SCREEN ON while activity is opening.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, I can't find a solutin already just add getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); in to onCreate();